# How to show a dynamically changing text inside CombBox ListView

Tags: java, text, dynamic, javafx, combobox

I want to show a dynamically changing loading text inside a `ComboBox` list while the contents of the list are being loaded. Showing some text while I'm getting the content is no issue. The issue is getting that text to change dynamically. This code will display a dynamically changing message as a `Label`:

```
import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.Event;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class SSCCE extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {

        VBox root = new VBox();

        final Label message = new Label("Loading");

        final Timeline timeline = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(
                Duration.ZERO, new EventHandler() {
                    @Override
                    public void handle(Event event) {
                        String messageText = message.getText();
                        message.setText(("Loading . . ."
                                .equals(messageText)) ? "Loading ."
                                : messageText + " .");
                    }
                }), new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(500)));
        timeline.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);

        root.getChildren().add(message);

        timeline.play();

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }
}
```

But the problem is that since putting `Node` objects into the item list is [strongly not recommended](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ComboBox.html)(And it looks really weird). I need to put them in something else.

I thought I solved this by using a `SimpleStringProperty` since it implements `Observable`:

```
import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.event.Event;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class SSCCE2 extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {

        VBox root = new VBox();

        final SimpleStringProperty message = new SimpleStringProperty("Loading");

        final Timeline timeline = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(
                Duration.ZERO, new EventHandler() {
                    @Override
                    public void handle(Event event) {
                        String messageText = message.getValue();
                        message.setValue(("Loading . . ."
                                .equals(messageText)) ? "Loading ."
                                : messageText + " .");
                    }
                }), new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(500)));
        timeline.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);

        ComboBox<SimpleStringProperty> comboBox = new ComboBox<SimpleStringProperty>();
        comboBox.getItems().add(message);

        timeline.play();

        root.getChildren().add(comboBox);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work. It just displays "Loading ." all the time. And yes. The `ComboBox` currently displays the `toString()` method of `SimpleStringProperty`, but that can easily be fixed by setting the cell factory or converter of the `ComboBox`. I didn't add that part here since I wanted to keep the example as small as possible. Also that kind of method would display the getValue() of SimpleStringProperty, which isn't `Observable`, and we're back to square one again.

Anyhow. With this example nothing happens. This is weird to me since `SimpleStringProperty` implements `Observable`, which should mean that any change will be displayed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To show the animated "Loading" message in the combo box itself, create a `ListCell` and update that from the timeline; then set it as the `buttonCell` for the `ComboBox`:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import javafx.animation.Animation;
import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.concurrent.Task;
import javafx.concurrent.Worker.State;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.control.ListCell;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class ComboBoxWithLoadingMessage extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {


        ComboBox<String> combo = new ComboBox<>();

        // mock loading task:
        Task<List<String>> loadingTask = new Task<List<String>>() {
            @Override
            public List<String> call() throws Exception {
                // mimic long loading process:
                Thread.sleep(5000);
                return Arrays.asList("One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five");
            }
        };

        loadingTask.setOnSucceeded(e -> 
            combo.getItems().setAll(loadingTask.getValue()));


        ListCell<String> buttonCell = new ListCell<String>() {
            @Override
            public void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
                super.updateItem(item, empty);
                State state = loadingTask.getState() ;
                if (state == State.SUCCEEDED ) {
                    if (empty) {
                        setText(null);
                    } else {
                        setText(item);
                    }
                } 
            }
        };          

        Timeline timeline = new Timeline(
                new KeyFrame(Duration.ZERO, e -> buttonCell.setText("Loading .")),
                new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(500), e -> buttonCell.setText("Loading . .")),
                new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(1000), e -> buttonCell.setText("Loading . . .")),
                new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(1500))
        );

        timeline.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE);

        loadingTask.stateProperty().addListener((obs, oldState, newState) -> {
            if (newState == State.RUNNING) {
                timeline.play();
            } else {
                timeline.stop();
                if (buttonCell.isEmpty()) {
                    buttonCell.setText(null);
                } else {
                    buttonCell.setText(buttonCell.getItem());
                }
            }
        });

        combo.setButtonCell(buttonCell);

        new Thread(loadingTask).start();

        StackPane root = new StackPane(combo);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 350, 120);

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

If you just want the "Loading..." message in the dropdown list, assuming the combo box will be empty until loading is complete, you can just use `ComboBox.setPlaceholder(...)`. Set the placeholder to a label whose text you change in the animation.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import javafx.animation.Animation;
import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.concurrent.Task;
import javafx.concurrent.Worker.State;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.ListCell;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class ComboBoxWithLoadingMessage extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {


        ComboBox<String> combo = new ComboBox<>();

        // mock loading task:
        Task<List<String>> loadingTask = new Task<List<String>>() {
            @Override
            public List<String> call() throws Exception {
                // mimic long loading process:
                Thread.sleep(5000);
                return Arrays.asList("One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five");
            }
        };

        loadingTask.setOnSucceeded(e -> 
            combo.getItems().setAll(loadingTask.getValue()));

        combo.setMinWidth(100);
        Label placeHolderLabel = new Label();
        combo.setPlaceholder(placeHolderLabel);

        Timeline timeline = new Timeline(
                new KeyFrame(Duration.ZERO, e -> placeHolderLabel.setText("Loading .")),
                new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(500), e -> placeHolderLabel.setText("Loading . .")),
                new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(1000), e -> placeHolderLabel.setText("Loading . . .")),
                new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(1500))
        );

        timeline.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE);

        loadingTask.stateProperty().addListener((obs, oldState, newState) -> {
            if (newState == State.RUNNING) {
                timeline.play();
            } else {
                timeline.stop();
                combo.setPlaceholder(null);
            }
        });     

        new Thread(loadingTask).start();

        StackPane root = new StackPane(combo);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 350, 120);

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

You can make the animation look a bit better with

```
.combo-box .placeholder {
    -fx-alignment: center-left ;
    -fx-padding: 5 ;
}
```

in an external stylesheet.

You could also consider just setting the placeholder to a `ProgressIndicator` and omitting the timeline, etc., which would be a simpler option.

Comment: This is good. But it is not exactly what I asked for. Is it possible to display this loading message in the `ComboBox` dropdown list instead of in the button cell? It is an absolut necessity in my application.

Comment: Yes, just do this in the cell factory instead of the button cell. I will update answer when I am back at the computer in a few hours

Comment: Assuming the list is empty until loading is complete, it's actually easier than that: just use the `comboBox.placeHolder` property. Updated code with that example.

Comment: In my implementation I instantiate the ComboBox and then I send the instance to another class and display it there (I want to start the task as soon as I start the app, but the ComboBox is displayed in another window). But the placeholder wont show unless I add it to a pane before I send it to the other class. Do you have any idea why?